# How to add a new ZF2' Zend\Form\Element within jQuery ajax

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework2, zend-form-select

I want to add a new ZF2' Zend\Form\Element within jQuery ajax. But while I use the Zend Form , I don't know how to make it. This is the add.phtml file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".pid").change(function(){
    var id = $('.pid').val();
    var $_this = $(this);
     $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo $this->url('Element/default',array('action'=>'change'));?>",
            data:"pid="+id,
            dataType:'json',
            async:false,
            success:function(data){
                if(data.response){
                   //here I want to add a new select  component after select conponent "pid" using like "$this->formRow($form->get('mid'))" or else .   
                }
            }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

the following is the remaining part of the html.

```
<?php
$title = 'add';
$this->headTitle($title);
?>
<h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>

<?php
$form = $this->form;

$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(
'Element/default',
array(
    'action'     => 'add'
 )
));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form); 
echo $this->formRow($form->get('pid'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('name'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('desc'));
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

How do I add a new zend form element within jquery ajax ? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry i'm lazy, but it's all explained within here: http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/07/04/new-zendform-features-explained/

Comment: I failed to open the website ..

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html#adding-new-elements-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You have script to receive data using ajax and view/html should be received by this script. You need controller/action to rendering data and return as response.

```
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;    
//some controller
public function changeAction(){ // your requested action
    //1. get partial helper to rendering html;
    $partial = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('partial');
    $form = new Form();// your form
    //2. render html
    $html = $partial('path/to/your/file/phtml',['form'=>$form]);
    //3. return data as JSON because in your ajax configuration dataType: 'json'
    return new JsonModel([
        'html' => $html,
    ]);
}
```

in your js success function should be:

```
success:function(data){
    if(data.html){
         $_this.find('blockToAppend').append(data.html);
    }
}
```